# android custom button with default selector

Tags: android

I have a listview in which i have an image and text content getting populated from the java code.

I'm unable to get the default orange selector working on the image. The image is placed ontop of button as `setBackgroundResource()` from Java.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: You should add some of your code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you could do change background by using drawable property of button in xml file. if you will use this setbackgroundresource() then it will ruin the effect of clicking on it. if u still want to use image as background source then u should create selector xml file for the button background.